# Make automapper load relations

Tags: c#, entity-framework, automapper

Why do I have to use `include` to make automapper load relations with EF core?

I have a list of ZipFiles with their corresponding File fields. Why doesn't automapper trigger lazy loading automatically for the fields I've defined?

```
_context.ZipFiles
  .Include(z => z.File) // <- why is this needed?
  .Select(_mapper.Map<Shared.Models.ZipFile>);
```

The mapping:

```
CreateMap<DatabaseFile, Shared.Models.DatabaseFile>();
CreateMap<ZipFile, Shared.Models.ZipFile>();
```

The target model:

```
public class ZipFile : Entity
{
    public DatabaseFile File { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

Comment: Use `ProjectTo` instead, And then you don't need `Include`.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu Good idea, it doesn't seem to utilize my mapping profile though, even if I pass the config `dataContext.ZipFiles.ProjectTo<ZipFile>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider);`

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Queryable-Extensions.html#supported-mapping-options Using `CreateProjection` will show you what's supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lazy loading isn't enabled by default. You have to [enable it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/lazy) explicitly.

You can also [mark some fields to be always auto included](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager?source=recommendations#model-configuration-for-auto-including-navigations) in your query. You will not have to `Include` them this way.